# Python Counter: Why I am getting the stopwords?

Tags: python, nltk

I have the list with words. I would like to count and check the most common words.

```
['project',
 'gutenberg',
 'ebook',
 'oliver',
 'twist',
 'may',......]
```

I have deleted stopwords from my list:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

data2 = data.split()
for x in data2:
    if x == "":
        data2.remove("")
    elif x in stopwords.words('english'):
        data2.remove(x)
```

When I would like to see results. It's great but I would like to sort the words.

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(data2)
Counter({'project': 88,
         'gutenberg': 98,
         'ebook': 13,
         'oliver': 881,
         'twist': 68,
```

Why I get stopwords? How to solve that?

```
Counter(data2).most_common(10)
[('the', 4746),
 ('a', 1943),
 ('said', 1232),
```

Comment: This isn't really a question about Python, but rather the `nltk` package, which I've now added for you.

Comment: You are iterating over a list while modifying its content. That is very wrong. Use `enumerate()` instead. `for i, x in enumerate(data2):`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: Assuming `data2` is a list of words formed from `data` being a space separated string? 

Its not best practice to modify a variable whilst you are iterating over it, so here you could do `clean_data = [x for x in data2 if (x != '' and x not in stopwords.words('English'))]` and then the function works

Answer (score 2):

It is best practice never to mutate a list inside a for/while loop while iterating through your list.
Example: Let's say you want to remove elements equal to 3 or 4 from the List `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 9]`.
What you are currently doing is:

```py
L = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 9]
to_remove = [3, 4]
for x in L:
    if x in remove:
        L.remove(x)
print(L) # will return -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 9]
```

What you really want is :

```py
L = [x for x in L if x not in to_remove]  # will return -> [1, 2, 5, 9]
```

Applying this logic to your code would give:

```py
data2 = [x for x in data2 if x != "" and x not in stopwords.words('english')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I run the first part of your code, and I am able to remove the stopwords.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

data = "This is an answer or an answer"
data2 = data.split()
for x in data2:
    if x == "":
        data2.remove("")
    elif x in stopwords.words('english'):
        data2.remove(x)
print(data2)
```

As an output I am getting: `['This', 'an', 'answer', 'an', 'answer']`.
Perhaps there is some problem with your indentation or how you are returning the data structure. I would suggest the following snippet:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

eng_stopwords = stopwords.words('english')

def remove_stopwords(sentence):    
    array_of_words = data.split()
    array_cleaned_words = list()
    for word in array_of_words:
        if len(word) == 0 or word in eng_stopwords:
            continue
        array_cleaned_words.append(word) # adding word only if not stopword
    return array_cleaned_words
```

Now you should be able to have the list of words without stopwords, and you can apply a simple word count with `collections`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit inefficient, you don't really need imports.

```
List=[...]

# Getting rid of empty strings and stop words:

to_remove=["","said","the","a"]

for i in to_remove:
    while i in List:
        List.remove(i)

# etc

# Getting top 10 most occurring words:

most_occurring_words=[]

for i in range(11):
    word=max(List,key=List.count) # gets the top most occurring word
    # remove the word from the list so we can get the second top etc
    while word in List:
        List.remove(word)

print(most_occurring_words)
```

Let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: "inefficient, you don't really need imports" -> The OP wants to incorporate `nltk` [stopwords](https://gist.github.com/sebleier/554280). Hard-coding such a list is cumbersome and isn't friendly when dealing with multiple languages

Comment: @Wondercricket Why not?